# Sending a String from JTextField on one JPanel to JTextArea on another JPanel via a button

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jtextfield, jtextarea

I am currently trying to take the typed text in the textField 'itemName' and have it print out on the text area 'printArea.'  When I have both printArea and itemName on the same JPanel (p1) it works just fine.  When printArea is set to a separate JPanel (itemName on p1 and printArea on p2), nothing prints out. Two JPanels are used to make the GUI appear as it was assigned. The area i Believe to be the issue is where I added JPanel 'p1' to JPanel 'p2'.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class MovieGUI extends JFrame{

JButton submit = new JButton("Submit");
JTextField itemName = new JTextField();
JTextField itemPrice = new JTextField();
JTextField itemQuantity = new JTextField();
JTextArea printArea = new JTextArea(400,400);


public MovieGUI(){


        JPanel p1 = new JPanel();

        p1.setLayout(new GridLayout(6, 2));



        p1.add(new JLabel("Item Name"));
        p1.add(itemName);   //p1.add(new JTextField(8));
        p1.add(new JLabel("Item Price"));
        p1.add(itemPrice);  // p1.add(new JTextField(8));
        p1.add(new JLabel("Quantity"));
        p1.add(itemQuantity);   //p1.add(new JTextField(8));
        p1.add(new JLabel("submit"));
        p1.add(submit);

        //Something is not working... 

        JPanel p2 = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
            p2.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            p2.add(p1, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        p2.add(printArea, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        //add(p1);  
        add(p2);

        event e = new event();
        submit.addActionListener(e);
    }


    public class event implements ActionListener{
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            String text = itemName.getText();

            printArea.setText(text);   //printArea.setText("BUTTON");


        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){


        MovieGUI frame = new MovieGUI();
        frame.setTitle("Submission");
        frame.setSize(800, 500);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `JPanel` `p2` does not contain nothing on `CENTER` alignment, so printArea doesn't view on `SOUTH` alignment. To see the `inputItem` text on `printArea` change from

```
p2.add(printArea, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
```

to

```
p2.add(printArea, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your text is being printed in `printArea`, but the first line (and more) of the `printArea` is hidden behind `p1`. This is because the south location with `printArea` is filling the entirety of `p2`, but it's z-index means it is behind `p1`. You can see this if you do:

```
p2.add(printArea, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
printArea.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
p2.setComponentZOrder(printArea, 0); // now the blue printArea hides the form elements in p1
```

To fix this: change printArea to `CENTER` instead of `SOUTH`.

#### Why?

It helps to understand how `BorderLayout` works to understand why. It is not splitting up the areas by percentage but it is used to arrange components around a centre panel. The order of the layout is:

1. North / South components will use their **preferred height**, and then the width of the component they're in.
2. I'll ignore East/West in here as you aren't using them.
3. Centre will use the **remaining space** after the N/S/E/W components have been sized

Your `printArea`'s preferred height was "huge" (technical term!), so it was trying to use that. Once in a centre panel it is told to use the remaining space only: as `p1` has a preferred height that is smaller than the `p2` height, the centre panel gets the remaining height and you can still see the `printArea`. You can also see this effect if you reverse the addition order when using NORTH/SOUTH; you would then only see the `printArea`, not the `p1` form.

If you take a look at the source of `BorderLayout` in the JDK, you can see the `layoutContainer` method where this all takes place.